# Creating Custom Protocol (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-7, protocols, network-protocols

I've been trying to create a custom protocol (open_php_file://) to open local files through the browser. I've created the following registery-keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
     open_php_file
          (Default) = "URL:PHPEd protocol"
          URL Protocol = ""
          DefaultIcon
               (Default) = "phped.exe"
          shell
               open
                    command
                         (Default) = "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\7.0\phped.exe" "%1"
```

The problem is: I can't open files in my browser (example: open_php_file://c:\file.txt), and the protocol isn't listed in the windows default programms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows?rq=1

Comment: the problem with this solution is that %1 gets replaced with "open_php_file://[file]" instead of just "[file]". This way I need some sort of filter that chops "open_php_file://".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile]
@="\"URL:openphpfile Protocol\""
"EditFlags"=hex:02,00,00,00
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\Programs\\CB\\Chunks\\CGI.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\Programs\\CB\\Chunks\\CGI.exe\" -c \"%1\""
```

Basically the problem was with the underscores in your protocol.Once removed everything started working fine.You can change the path of executable as per your wish i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\7.0\phped.exe".

I tried `openphpfile:blast` and it worked quite nicely :)

EDIT:

> the problem with this solution is that %1 gets replaced with
>   "open_php_file://[file]" instead of just "[file]". This way I need
>   some sort of filter that chops "open_php_file://".

put a space after openphpfile:[Space]Your_Content and change parameter to %2 you will get the expected result

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\openphpfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\Programs\\CB\\Chunks\\CGI.exe\" -c \"%2\""
```

Comment: It works without adding the `EditFlags` value and `DefaultIcon` key, interesting. Thanks for this, using on Win7.

Comment: @perilbrain This solution works fine on windows 7 but not on windows 10, can you suggest something for windows 10.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but as @MadhurSodhi mentioned, this method doesn't work on Windows 10. That would be super useful, completely eliminating the need of a "middleware" for the argument parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Windows always replaces %1 with the full URI that was entered. AFAIK there is no way to change that behavior.

This leaves you two options:

1. If you've written the program being called yourself, you can filter the URI when it is being invoked.
2. You could use an intermediate program that acts as a filter for the URI and then forwards the result to the actual protocol implementation. Fortunately for you, someone has already done exactly that. See '[CustomURL](http://customurl.codeplex.com/)' on CodePlex. CustomURL is a small utility for registering custom URL protocols. For example you can associate the rdp:// protocol with Remote Desktop Client or the ssh:// protocol with Putty or another SSH client.