# Creating Custom Protocol for xdebug.file_link_format and Sublime Text 2 on windows

Tags: windows, protocols, xdebug, sublimetext2

I am trying to make it so that I can click on links outputted by xdebug and open the files that have a problem like in textmate only I am trying to do this with ST2 on windows xp.

I tried to use the [SublimeProtocol](https://bitbucket.org/sublimator/sublimeprotocol) plugin to accomplish this task but the format of the links it expects in order to open a file are like the following:

`sblm:///C/Users/name/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%202/Packages/`

and the xdebug.file_link_format is:
`xdebug.file_link_format="sblm://%f?%l"`

which outputs this this type of link: `sblm://C:\wamp\www\busadv\parse3.php?10`

so ST2's console indicates that it is unable to open the file.

Then I tried creating a custom protocol based on SO question [Creating Custom Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671261/creating-custom-protocol-windows-7)
since this seemed to be in line with what I was trying to accomplish. I created a reg file with the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm]
@="\"URL:sblm Protocol\""
"EditFlags"=hex:02,00,00,00
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\" -c \"%1\""
```

The problem is when I click the link output by xdebug a file **DOES** open in ST2 only file one that is originating in the directory of the browser and not where xdebug is saying its at. I tried replacing the %1 with %2 so the file would chop of the parts before C:\ but the file never opens when that replacement is used. So what are the other parameter needed in order for this to work?

**UPDATE:**

Added a batch file that contains the following:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set SUBLIME=%1
set FILE=%~2
%SUBLIME% --open "%FILE:~19%"
```

and changed the registry to include the .bat as suggested for [windows and netbeans](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) to :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm]
@="URL:sblm Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Sublime Text\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe,1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sblm\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\sublime.bat\" \"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe\" \%1\""
```

Also changed the xdebug.file_link_format to
`xdebug.file_link_format="sblm://open/?f=%f:%l"`

now ST2 still opens a file but it is from the browser directory with the link included almost but excludes C:\w.

For example xdebug link
sblm://open/?f=C:\wamp\www\busadv\parse3.php:10

the file opened in ST2 is
C:\Program Files\SRWare Iron\amp\www\busadv\parse3.php