# Open a specific file only via windows registry

Tags: windows, registry

I want to open only one specific text file after opening notpad.exe via windows registry. suppose I have one name.txt. I want to open that text file through notepad.exe and put it on the web. So every time I open the url and hit a button, the button will call notepad.exe and open that specific name.txt file. I have seen that calling notepad.exe is possible. But can I open one perticuler text file every time through notepad.exe ?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]
  [< ProtocolName >]
      (Default) = "URL:My App Protocol Handler"
      URL Protocol = ""
    [DefaultIcon]
       (Default) = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
    [shell]
       [open]
         [command]
           (Default) = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe "%1""
```

I just want to know after this point can I put any other path or something to specify the text file?

Comment: I solved it. Via [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671261/creating-custom-protocol-windows-7

Comment: At the end where the command is getting executed put "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" "C:\myDocuments\name.txt" "%1"