# Invoking Win32 application from email body

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am working in an application. In this user enter his email id to get the some application setting.

After some time he will get mail with settings embedded and an apply button. Once user click on that we need to set the setting (in some file or registry).

Desktop application will read the setting(File / Registry) once it is launched.

This is the requirement. My question is,

How to call Win32/MFC application on clicking apply button with setting parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot arbitrarily execute something in an email message for obvious reasons.

The closest integration you could get would be to pass the configuration data as an argument to a [custom URL handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) in an HTML anchor; your mileage would likely vary wildly depending on browser/email client/webmail service so this is a bad idea.

Far better to simply send the configuration as an attachment with a file extension associated with your application and tell the user to open it, your app reads the config file and your done.

Comment: +1, Or it can be done using signed ActiveX and Trusted web site.IE only.

Comment: Thanks for u r replay. it worked for me. one thing. when i run the command in IE it worked fine. But i run the same command in crome it failed.

Comment: Which API i need to use to register custom URL handler. do i need to use registry API's to set it, or do i need to use some other API to register it.