# Run .exe from JavaScript cross-browser

Tags: javascript, activex, exe, hta, activex-exe

I know how to run an `.exe` using ActiveX, but that is Internet Explorer only, and I also know how with `.hta`, but that has to be installed/used as an application.

This doesn't have to be online: actually I'd prefer this locally.

This doesn't have to work with all browsers: the solution could would only with Firefox.

Thank you a lot in advance! :)

Comment: you comment about .hta is windows only, but .exe is windows only.

Comment: @kennypu sorry. :) I mean't that it has to be installed as an application. :) I just edited my question to fix this illogical moment. :)

Comment: I'm assuming the downvote is because you are asking how to do something that is considered highly unethical by most web developers.

Comment: @AlexWayne I woudn't be doing this from my website.
I'm just curious if this could be accomplished locally, with prompting. I would NOT do this on any public-facing site.

Comment: Personally I suspect that it was because the title says "cross-browser" while the text says "firefox"

Comment: @Jeff cross-browser would be great, but Firefox would also suffice, as I explained in my question.

Comment: it's not very cross-browser if it only works on windows  :)

Comment: @Eevee lol you know what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can run a .exe from Firefox using `nsIProccess` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Running_applications so you should look into that.

however, it is not advisable to run a .exe from browser, as this can make your site look malicious.

I couldn't find anyway for chrome. however, you can load external libraries using the NPAPI, this may work for exe as well but I have no clue: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: I wouldn't be doing this from my website.
I'm just curious if this could be accomplished locally, with prompting. And your answer explained that. :) I would never do this in any public-facing site.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept your answer. :) Didn't know that this was possible. :D But one thing- just curious- this is locally right? Also, is there any similar technique for Chrome?

Comment: I couldn't find anyway for chrome. however, you can load external libraries using the NPAPI, this may work for exe as well but I have no clue: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: _+1 and accept_ Wow thanks a lot! :) Could you maybe edit you answer to also include the Chrome solution please? Thanks. :)

Comment: The links in this answer are now broken, but I found another solution, using a [custom URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) to run an `.exe` from the browser.