# How to launch client machine exe file and not dependent on browser?

Tags: java, javascript

I want to launch a exe file when click on the button from my appliction and that should be from client machine. I tried with following solutions.
    **`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".....\\somefile.exe");`**

when I follows the above solution then it was opened server machine exe file. 
I applied one more solution in script code
i.e

```
**var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec("...\\somefile.exe");**
```

the above code working fine but I need to enable ActiveX related script enble mode in client browser window manually and it is only applied for IE only.
Let me know any solution that is browser independent and without activex enable option.

Comment: I'm not saying this isn't possible, but it is really bad practice. You should take some time and think about if you really NEED to do this.

Comment: If you can run a setup on the client machine this can be accomplished in IE, FF & Chrome quite easily with a custom protocol handler "location.href='myapp://run'" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) not sure about Opera.

Comment: Every Hacker out there wants this too!

Comment: But I have to launch a installed file (exe file) when user clicks on a button. I didn't get other than this solution.

Comment: Most of the browsers won't allow this directly. In chrome you can't even open a downloaded .exe file directly :)

Comment: sounds like a hack !!

Comment: If this worked (so easily), it would pose a major security threat! Whatever makes you want to do this: Better find another way.