# Open custom application from web page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open any custom application say VLC Player or any other installed application in the system through HTML page. I have tried WScript.shell technique but no luck.

Comment: There are no standards-based browser API's to do this, and with good reason.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried from the WScript.shell technique?

Comment: I used this code:

WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                WshShell.Run(filepath, 1, false);

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in general. There's no way to open any arbitrary application from a webpage. Here are some scenarios where it's still possible. One possibility: some programs have protocol handlers associated with them, and those can be launched through a link or via javascript (e.g. `window.location = "someprotocol:path?argument=value"`). I don't think VLC (to use your example) is among them, however.

There might be a more useful solution if you limit yourself to a particular browser/OS.

Comment: can i make protocol handlers for my custom application ? if yes then how ?

Comment: Check here and elsewhere on Stack Overflow for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows