# Not able to run .exe file on the browser

Tags: .net

I host the site where is my .exe file is present on the IIS SEVER.
When I run the site on the browser that .exe file get downloaded.
I want to run that .exe file on browser. What should I do?

Waiting for the answser.....
Rhutuja

Comment: Browsers are not supposed to host and/or run exe files.

Comment: Executable files cannot be run on a browser. If you try to access through the browser, it will get the download.

Comment: Thank you ....Then how can I consume/call my .exe file from other machine to my machine.Iwant to fetch .exe file file from x machine to y machine?

Comment: If the .exe is already installed, you can [register a protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) to open it from the browser.