# Start an .exe from React.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exe

Is there a possible way to start an .exe application on shared location from react.js app.

The approach should be working on internet explorer also.

Comment: React is UI library, it isn't responsible for such things. And the answer is no. Guess what would happen if any web application were capable of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with a custom URL handler.  For example :

1. JavaScript code can navigate to a URL like (myexehandler://parameters)
2. Exe can be registered as handler for "myexehandler://"

Browser will delegate handling of custom URLs to OS and OS will invoke the exe.

Documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa767914 , [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)