# How can i run .exe file from webpage?

Tags: html

I want to open .exe file from web page by django, but i can't find any possible way. my exe file will streaming video file(using darknet), and i can't find a way to convert it to  mp4. my goal is run webpage on local.

Is it really impossible even in local environment?
please tell me any idea.

Comment: Are you writing a virus distribution platform? :-) This is a not a good idea.

Comment: of course not. i edit my question. can you help me?

Comment: You want to do something no modern browser will support. you need to rethink your approach

Comment: You can [register a custom URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) to open an .exe from a web page.