# Launching local application from custom email button

Tags: html

I am sending a custom mail to the users via Gmail which includes the following button code

```
<a href="">launch</a>
```

on the click of the button, I need to open a locally installed application like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/). I don't have access to the user system for `Registry editor` entries.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try something like this: window.open("data:x-application/myapp;,12345");

Comment: You have mentioned, locally installed application like 'TeamViewer', what other applications are you targeting?

Comment: [ActiveXObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject)

Comment: @Code_Ninja We need to open our custom windows application for simplicity have given the example of TeamViewer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Comment: @Progman I don't have access to the user systems to create a new key in Registry editor.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey ActiveXObject is only supported via IE and I am looking for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd window.open("data:x-application/myapp;,12345"); didn't work

Comment: I guess For security purposes, browsers are not allowed to open any application in user OS