# Need to run .exe game file inside web page

Tags: html, wordpress, web, hosting, exe

I have a .exe game in a folder (it's running without setup) and need to upload it to my hosting so it can view and run it inside my website WordPress page, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be very stupid and unsafe to give browsers the control to run any binary executable via any webpage

Comment: Using an emulator such as [BoxedWine](http://www.boxedwine.org/documentation/), it is possible to run .exe files in the browser.

Comment: @AndersonGreen even if so, you would be very limited in what you can do, the browser simply cant communicate properly with the outside world, outside of the browser

Comment: It's also possible to open an executable from the browser using a [custom URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, but then the executable wont run *within* the browser, it will just launch a seperate process