# Launch Python Script with Pythonw from Batch and give it Focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, windows-10, pythonw

I'm on Windows 10 and I have a PyQt5 Application I launch using a .bat file to use the venv interpreter.

When I call the script using `python my_script.py` it opens the main window in focus, but also shows the Python console in background. To get rid of the console, I tried launching it with `pythonw my_script.py`, but then it silently opens in background.

I tried things like `window.setWindowState(Qt.WindowState.WindowActive)` or `window.setFocus()`, but this only makes the icon blink in the task bar. Other Google results said that Windows does not allow programs to easily grab focus anymore, but then again, `python` can do it on start-up, so I would like to replicate that behavior with `pythonw`.

Below you can find testing code and the batch file, context was launching it from a custom URI protocol.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205984 to register any protocol for testing

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test App")

        label = QLabel(title)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        the_title = "I got no arguments"
    else:
        the_title = f"I was run with argument {sys.argv[1]}"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow(the_title)
    window.show()
    window.setFocus()
    app.exec()
```

and

```
cd %~dp0
call ..\venv\Scripts\activate
start "" "pythonw" "test_url_scheme_one.py" "%1"
deactivate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the batch file with the following fixed it:

```
start "" "C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe" "C:\path\to\my_script.py" "%1"
```

Now the window gets started in foreground and in focus.