# Problem with starting Games from Epic Games in a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

So i'm writing on a Batch Script to Optimize Games and i found the following way to start Games from Epic Games in cmd:

```
start "" "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102%3A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50cca%3A9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch&silent=true"
```

This is now for GTAV and it works fine typing it manually in cmd however as soon when i put it in a Batch Script it just opens the Epic Games Window but doesn't start the Game.

I also tried to run the command in a seperate cmd window like that:

```
start cmd.exe "start "" "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102%3A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50cca%3A9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch&silent=true""
```

But it still does nothing. It just says that it can't find silent or it's written wrong.
Also the echo shows that are spaces in the command now:

```
start cmd.exe "start "" "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50ccaA9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch  & silent=true""
```

Maybe someone else knows what's wrong or why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Url use the shortcut .url file created by epic launcher, in my case the shortcut is saved on Desktop with file name "Game Name.url".

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\username\Desktop"
start "" "Game Name.url"

exit
```

It also auto launches Epic Launcher if not running.

**Note**: Remove any special character in file name if present.

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you so much! It is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

My skills with cmd are rusted and I cant recreate this specific code, but did you try:

```
start "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50ccaA9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch"
```

Comment: This just Opens the Epic Games WIndow but doesn't start the Game

Answer (score 0):

```
::epic games

::check if EpicGamesLauncher.exe is running already
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq EpicGamesLauncher.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "EpicGamesLauncher.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (

::start epic games itself
:: has to be opened like a website link
start "" com.epicgames.launcher://apps

::clears screen not to confuse user during timeout due to weird start command error ("The system cannot find the drive specified.")
cls
echo EpicGamesLauncher.exe is NOT running!
echo Starting Epic Game Launcher...
:: waits x seconds for epic launcher to load
TIMEOUT /T 15

)

::this will start if epic games is open, if not it will just open epic games itself, need double %% because this is a batch file
::com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102%3A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50cca%3A9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch&silent=true
start "" com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102%%3A6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50cca%%3A9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch&silent=true


exit
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since this was modified 2 months ago, i hope someone will still see this:

The batch command is the following:

```
START "" "A:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe" com.epicgames.launcher://apps/0584d2013f0149a791e7b9bad0eec102:6e563a2c0f5f46e3b4e88b5f4ed50cca:9d2d0eb64d5c44529cece33fe2a46482?action=launch&silent=true
```

The first "" is just a title for the new "window" you're creating. If not provided the cmd will think the exe will be the title and the url the right programm to start. Just bad style

The EpicGamesLauncher.exe will be the right programm to start. I found it with help of the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows) question. Just look for the "com.epicgames.launcher" protocol.

The third part u get by creating a Shortcut to your game in eg. (RMB on Game -> Manage -> Create Desktop Link) Then go in the shortcut properties and under webdocument you can find the url property. This is the third part but you need to decode the url encoding. For GTA i had multiple "%3A" in it, this translates to a simple ":".

It works on my Win10 maschine. And i hope it will work on your maschine as well.