# How can I request the user to open Desktop Application in React?

Tags: c#, reactjs, windows, web-applications

I couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for. I have two applications - web application built with react and desktop application built in C# Forms. What I want is if the user goes to a certain page in the Web Application, the browser should open (with or without a request) the windows application and send data, like the user's id. Could you guys give me an advice how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, when installing your windows C# form in the user machine, you need to register a custom  protocol in the registery.

See [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)