# Register a custom URL protocol in Windows doesn't open my file?

Tags: c#, windows, url-scheme, custom-url-protocol

I am trying to make a custom protocol to open my c# windows application through a web application following the first comment's steps here: [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)
After setting everything up, I got to the last part where I have to type the link. Internet Explorer knows that I have to open some sort of a file but it requires a different reader.

[image]
Here is the protocol I made.

[image]
And this is the path, I have copied it, so it should be correct!

[image]
This is the folder of the program that I want to open.

[image]
Here is what happens when I go to that website. As you can see, I need to allow the browser to open the app.

[image]
And here is the problem. Any solutions to that? Of course, I can open normally the .exe file without getting any errors.