# Windows 10 JavaScript Invoking a batch file using custom protocol fails

Tags: javascript, registry, custom-protocol

I created a new entry into the Registry (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)). The entry is shown in the following snapshot:

[image: Registry]

Once this entry was defined, I used the following piece of code to verify that the Batch script is invoked from a JavaScript function:

```
Save_Result = async () => {
                        const location = window.location.hostname;
                        const settings = {
                                            method: 'POST',
                                            headers: {
                                                        Accept: 'application/json',
                                                        'Content-Type': 'application/text',
                                                     }
                                         };
                  try {
                  const fetchResponse = await fetch(`FDMyAlbsIF: "asdads" "dfgdfg" "dfgdfgert"` , settings);
        const data = await fetchResponse.text;
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }    
}
Save_Result () ;
```

Obviously, I'm not doing things correctly as I got the following error message:

```
Fetch API cannot load fdmyalbsif: "asdads" "dfgdfg" "dfgdfgert". URL scheme "fdmyalbsif" is not supported.
```

The question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to invoke this custom URL manually and/or in a tool like Postman?  That is, is the custom URL itself failing on the machine, or is the attempt to use it *with fetch* failing?  (Because the latter wouldn't surprise me at all, there are limitations on what AJAX operations can be invoked from a web page for security reasons.)

Comment: Well @David... I'm entering the url `FDMyAlbsIF://aaa` and the browser searches the web for something like that. I tend to interpret this as protocol definitions issue. Am I right?

Comment: In that case it does indeed sound like an issue with the custom protocol and not so much with the JavaScript code.  It's probably best to shift the focus from the code to the implementation of the protocol.  Is there any difference in behavior between different browsers?  How about if you test the protocol/URL in a Windows Explorer instance instead of a browser?  Basically, if the problem is the custom protocol then we should focus on testing/validating that before moving on to any code which internally uses it.

Comment: @David, I tried entering `FDMyAlbsIF://aaa` in windows explorer and, indeed, it asked for an application to open the link. Taking into account the needs (please refer to the body of the question and the snapshot of the regedit), could you post what should be the correct definition of the registry entry? The aim is to run a batch file at a given location in a local disk with up to 4 parameters. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the correct Custom Protocol definition into the Registry (It works when using it in Windows Explorer as suggested by David above) and it works. There are still some issues to tackle though (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064430/windows-10-custom-protocol-fails-when-invoked-from-javascript-while-it-works-v)).