# Windows 10 - Custom Protocol fails when invoked from JavaScript while it works via other methods

Tags: javascript, batch-file, windows-10, custom-protocol

I successfully defined into the Registry a Custom protocol (named `FDMyAlbsIF`). The protocol is aimed to invoke a Batch File that performs different actions depending on the received parameters.

I face two problems right now:

1. When invoking the protocol via Windows Explorer (i.e. entering into the path field the string `FDMyAlbsIF:\\ AAA BBB CCC`), the batch file is indeed invoked and its actions are seen (right now I just echo into a file the received command with whatever parameters are entered). When invoked from JavaScript, I get and error message that reads: `Fetch API cannot load fdmyalbsif:\ "AAA" "BBB" "CCC". URL scheme "fdmyalbsif" is not supported.`
2. When checking the contents of the tempo file, I see that the parameters are not passed the way I need since it is showing `"fdmyalbsif:\\%20AAA%20BBB%20TTT" "" "" ""`

The definitions of the protocol within the Registry are:

```
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FDMyAlbsIF /t REG_SZ /d "My Description" /f
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FDMyAlbsIF /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FDMyAlbsIF\shell /f
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FDMyAlbsIF\shell\open /f
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FDMyAlbsIF\shell\open\command /t REG_SZ /d d:\MiAlbs\Manipulate_Files.bat "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" /f
```

The code I use within the JavaScript to invoke the Batch File is:

```
Save_Result = async () => {
                        const location = window.location.hostname;
                        const settings = {
                                            method: 'POST',
                                            headers: {
                                                        Accept: 'application/text',
                                                        'Content-Type': 'application/text',
                                                     }
                                         };
                  try {
                  const fetchResponse = await fetch(`FDMyAlbsIF:\\ "AAA" "BBB" "CCC"` , settings);
        const data = await fetchResponse.text;
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }    
}
Save_Result () ;
```

My guess is that the use of **post** is inconsistent with the Custom Protocol, but I don't quite know how to phrase this request.

### Edit

One more thing that may be important: When invoking the Batch File, there are some cases where one of the parameters is a multi-line string. I need this string to be received into the Batch File as-is.

Comment: 1) Custom protocols are never supported with `fetch`. 2) The parameters are passed correctly, this is a URL so spaces and some other things need to be URL-encoded. You need to decode them. A batch file is probably not a good choice for a protocol handler anyway - write a proper program or at least use a VBS or JS file or a PowerShell script.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT for your feedback. The application I'm developing is to be used privately, without the need for a Web Server (it works!!!). As such, I prefer to keep things as simple as possible (for me of course) unless what I wish to do proves to be impossible or extremely complex. In any case, if you know what method I should use within the JavaScript (much as Zoom does), it will solve one of my problems. Thanks again.

Comment: That's what I meant - using batch is making your life unnecessarily harder because you can't even handle a URL properly there!

Comment: @CherryDT, it's been many years since I wrote something in BV/VBS. I could spend some time refreshing my memory if there is no proper solution for what I want to do. For the time being, I'll wait to see if someone shares a feasible solution to my problems. Incidentally, I recall seeing a post in this forum with explanations on how to pass parameters to a Batch File from JavaScript. Unfortunately, I can't find it again.