# Windows-10 Interface between JavaScript and Batch file executed using a Custom Protocol

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, custom-protocol

This is a continuation of [another post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064430/windows-10-custom-protocol-fails-when-invoked-from-javascript-while-it-works-v?noredirect=1#comment135856557_77064430) which is not as yet fully resolved.

I'm invoking (from JavaScript using a Custom Protocol) a batch file to perform a number of possible operations (depending on the passed parameters). The Batch file receives all parameters within %1, something like:

```
"fdmyalbsif:%5C%20Action_1%20Append%20%5B%0A%7B%22File%22:%2220230602_101157.jpg%22,%22Type%22:%22jpg%22,%22Keys%22:%22Pepe%22%7D,%0A%7B%22File%22:%2220230602_101205.jpg%22,...
```

where:

1. `fdmyalbsif` is the protocol name,
2. `Action_1` indicates what the batch file needs to do (there are 6 different actions),
3. `Append` is an option for `Action_1`,
4. The remaining string is **part** of a JSON array ("part" due to the limitations of batch file input length).

In order to perform whatever is requested, I first need to parse the received string into the three (sometimes 4) parts that follow `fdmyalbsif`. Most importantly, the JSON part must be turned into a JSON without HEXA replacements since this part is to be saved into a file (i.e. it takes few iterations to complete the whole transfer such that the first invocation creates the file while the remaining invocations append to the end of the file).

As such, I need to write replacement of `%22` to `"`, `%4B` to `[`, `%5D` to `]` and so forth.

I made some trials based on [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_replace_string.htm) page but, apparently, the presence of `%` in the input string sabotages things. Also tried escaping this character with another `%` without success.

Last, I'm aware that there are alternative implementations (VBS, compiled programs, etc.) but I'd like to attempt completing this approach before giving up.

### Edit

The desired result of the manipulations would be to be able to allow acting based on the provided information after splitting the received string into:

- Action_1
- Append
- The partial JSON as (this is just an example of course):

```
{"File":"20230602_101449.jpg","Type":"jpg","Keys":"null"},
{"File":"20230602_101540.jpg","Type":"jpg","Keys":"null"},
{"File":"20230602_103726.jpg","Type":"jpg","Keys":"null"},
{"File":"20230602_104433.mp4","Type":"mp4","Keys":"null"},
```

Comment: can you please share the desired output for the above string?

Comment: The advice is no different to your last incarnation, use a scripting language capable of URI encoding/decoding. It's no good saying that you'd "like to attempt completing this approach before giving up", when all indications are that you have not in fact attempted anything, _(other than some hearsay percent escaping)_. If you have then [Edit] your question to submit it, and tell us which specific part you'd like us to help you to fix. This is not a code to order service, we help you with your own code.

Comment: Thank you @Compo for your feedback. In fact, I did tried many things to achieve some manual decoding and found no point in listing them here. I agree that something like vbs would be more swited for this task and will give it some considerations. Also a c++ program is an option. If you could recommend other options (taking into account the "environment") please do.

Comment: Asking for software, utilities etc. is off topic on StackOverflow. (You are not a new member here so should be aware of how things are supposed to be done). If you don't see the point in showing us what you want us to help you with, then why would we see any point in helping you. This is a two way process, you have to show us that you're one of those 'ways'.

Comment: Thank you @Bluepanthor for your response. I edited the question with the information you requested.

Comment: @Compo I don't see the port in sharing information that does not contribute to present the problem (in my opinion at least) while it "contaminates" the presentation. This, of course, is a matter of taste and your taste is as valid as mine. Thank you anyway for your interest.

Comment: @FDavidov It's easy to see the point of showing what you have tried: stackoverflow contributors will generally refuse to answer questions without it. So the point of sharing that information is to get people to answer your question.

Comment: I have found a way but first can share you the closest approach to it so it can help

Comment: Hello @Bluepanthor, my apologies but I don't quite understand your message. Do you want me to share something or you want to share with me? If the last, you can pose an answer to this question. If not, please be more specific on what do you want me to share. Thanks.