# Replacement for an old embedded dll in html page

Tags: c#, html, angular, webassembly

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is designed to run on IE.

The app is using the `<object>` tag to embed a DLL that all it's purpose is to run an EXE file on the client's computer.

This app is used on a local network in our company so we gave it the permissions to do that.

Now we are switching to Angular which will run on any modern browser. The approach of embedding DLL in html is not possible anymore.

This web page most be able eventually to run this EXE. Without any Web API. It most be directly from the web page.

Which is the best way to do that?

Is it possible with webAssembly?

Comment: what is the desire to keep it on IE when this is dead and has been for some time? Its not possible to do exactly what you want through Web Assembly and I think however you try its going to cause a lot of pain. 

have you got access to the original source code as you might need to re-write how things happen. Maybe trigger an Azure function or something?

Comment: Everything in a browser is aimed at preventing a web site from executing programs on the client's computer, because that would be a serious security risk. Now you didn't tell us anything about the EXE you want to run, so all we can give you are some general suggestions. For instance, it would be possible to write a program that runs on the client and acts as a web server on the client. You can call that server from within a web page: `http://localhost:1234/run?app=my_exe` and then this new app will run your EXE. Please do think hard about the security implications of such an app.

Comment: I suspect that nowadays this can only be done using a custom protocol handler, which would need to be registered on each of the client's PCs. This requires that you / your organization has control over the machines, but I guess that's also how the exe was distributed. See e.g. [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/80650/1220550) and [Custom Protocol Handling — How To (Note: MEDIUM link)](https://medium.com/swlh/custom-protocol-handling-how-to-8ac41ff651eb).

Comment: *"all it's purpose is to run an EXE file on the client's computer."* - whether it can run as web assembly depends on what it do.

Comment: @PeterB This is very interesting. ill check it out.