# Register custom URL Protocol with multiple commands

Tags: windows, registry

I have registered the following in Windows 10 registry, but all the invocations I am making such as:

```
mycustomprot://launch
mycustomprot://run
mycustomprot://edit
```

are all attempting to launch wordpad.exe.

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot]
    @="URL:mycustomprot Protocol"
    "URL Protocol"=""
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot\DefaultIcon]
    @="\"C:\\path\\to\\icon.ico\""
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot\shell]
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot\shell\edit\command]
    @="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe\" \"%1\""
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot\shell\launch\command]
    @="\"%windir%\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe\" \"%1\""
    
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprot\shell\run\command]
    @="\"C:\\Program Files\\AnyDesk\\AnyDesk.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you pruned protocol name:  `@="URL:mycustomprot"` instead of   `@="URL:mycustomprot Protocol"`

Comment: @Daemon-5 Tried it, no luck.