# HTML email button - Launch Outlook Macro

Tags: html, vba, outlook

In my application, I am sending a HTML-formatted email using SQL Mail through my VB.net application.  While I can add a button to the email, can someone advise if and how I could have that button attached to a VBA macro within Outlook, so, when clicked, I can launch an application?

The VBA is quite simple, it launches an application on our server.

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim strArgument As String

strProgramName = "W:\Oscar\Oscar.exe"
strArgument = "ticket_system"

Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this need to work only for you, or for multiple recipients?  If other people are included, how much control do you have over their desktop environments?

Comment: It needs to work for everyone within the organization.  I can make sure that each computer has the macro installed in their desktop Outlook.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to trigger a macro from a button in an email.  You might consider using a custom protocol and triggering the action from a link - eg. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows  or maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN