Run a local PS1 batch from web site page
I have a simple powershell script, like this:
Write-Output "Hello"

saved on local disk C: and I would like to call it from a web page (https://mysite/page.html).
I tried several solutions converting ps1 to exe (using PS2EXE), all these DON'T WORKS:
<button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/myprogram.exe')">
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/myprogram.exe')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function RunExeFile(){
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("C:\myprogram.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RunExeFile()">run exe</a>

I also tried using Werbrun ( https://www.webrunapps.com/ ) adding the following tag to html page
<a href="webrun:C:\myprogram.exe">Run exe with Webrun</a>

but I get the following error:
"It seems that C:\myprogram.exe is not a valid executable. Please check your syntax."
PS. By launching the exe locally it works fine
Thanks.
UPDATE 10-08-2024
Placing the exe in the C:\Windows folder everything works correctly (os: Win 11-64b)

This is unable to work since you cannot run any executable file in HTML. While there are multiple reasons behind this, a large one is because of safety issues. If an executable was able to be run at the press of a button online, it would allow for the transmission of malicious code. I hope this helps! If you wish to use Webrun, please note that it will only work on computers that have Webrun installed. Also make sure to specify the whole path, which I see that you have not done in your question above.

Hi bobbybob65536, Webrun would be a solution and it is installed on local computer but it doesn't seem to be able to use the ps1 converted to exe.

Looking at the Webrun website, it seems to say this: "WebRun is a software for Windows that allows you to run any program installed on your PC, simply by clicking a link inside an HTML page." What might be occurring is that the executable you have is doing something other than running a program installed on your PC. This is most likely to prevent malicious code from being executed.

Perhaps, in any case I wrote to Webrun support, PS2EXE creates a stand alone executable without requiring installation. Perhaps this could be the reason. I also tried registering a protocol in Windows following this guide ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows ) but I couldn't do it .

Would you be able to confirm that my above reason is not why this issue is happening? If there is no way that you may use Webrun, try a language that will support popup windows and program your GUI inside that. You could try using Python with the TKinter or PyGame modules.

I am open to any solution. The origin of everything is an efficient management of serial ports and I thought of using Powershell. Maybe I'll have to use WebSerial API.
